# How to center a showmodalbottomservice

Tags: flutter

Im trying to center an showmodalbottomService because when im typing, you can't see the textfield... means you can't see what you are typing.

I've tried it with SingleChildScrollView, Center or with the mainAxisAlignment... but it's just not working. Please help me!

Can anyone tell me what's the problem?

Here is my code:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) => Center(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      height: 250,
                      color: Colors.green,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Task hinzufügen',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                                child: Icon(Icons.close),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Divider(thickness: 1.8),
                          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                          TextField(
                            controller: _taskController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                              ),
                              filled: true,
                              hintText: 'Task hinzufügen',
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                          Container(
                            padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            // height: 200.0,
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  width:
                                      (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2) -
                                          20,
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    child: Text(
                                      'RESET',
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () => _taskController.text = '',
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  width:
                                      (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2) -
                                          20,
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                    color: Colors.blue,
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Hinzufügen',
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () => saveData(),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `isScrollControlled: true` to `showModalBottomSheet` function.

Then you have to:

- remove the `Center` as a parent.
- remove first `Column` (optional step, as it is useless here).
- remove the height from `Container`.
- add a bottom margin of the keyboard height (This is `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom` here).

Your code will become like this:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  builder: (BuildContext context) => SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
      ),
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Task hinzufügen',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                child: Icon(Icons.close),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Divider(thickness: 1.8),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          TextField(
            controller: _taskController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
              ),
              filled: true,
              hintText: 'Task hinzufügen',
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            // height: 200.0,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2) - 20,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text(
                      'RESET',
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => _taskController.text = '',
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2) - 20,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Text(
                      'Hinzufügen',
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => saveData(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: but now the problem is, that the card is at the bottom of the screen... means it too high... how can i change that?

Comment: @LucasKnötig I have edited my answer, take a look.